# I need to change the category line color

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise

please see campsalesau.com and on the left side there is a category menu, I need to change the line color between each category from black to grey, please help.

Comment: hi frinds only  css change in insert code:-border-color: grey;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi change color code on below mention border-color

```
#nav_vert hr {
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  border-color: -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color #ddd;
  border-image: none;
  border-style: none none solid;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 224px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much very helpful.. I found out last night too... Thank you for help